# Serenity properties

Tags: cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

How do I use serenity properties for running cucumber jvm?

E.g:

```
serenity.use.unique.browser=true
serenity.requirement.types=Epics,Features
serenity.take.screenshots=FOR_FAILURES
serenity.sourceDirectory=./target/site/serenity
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is it that you are trying to achieve? These are serenity's configuration properties. They take effect once you build your project. That's pretty much it. Take a look at [Serenity Reference Manual](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_serenity_system_properties_and_configuration) for an in-depth explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Github:
https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber

An example of using cucumber with serenity can be found here:
https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-articles/tree/master/introduction-to-serenity-with-cucumber/src/samples/etsy-tester

Which points to the example code from the article found at:
http://thucydides.info/docs/articles/an-introduction-to-serenity-bdd-with-cucumber.html

Comment: Do you know, am I able to use serenity without serenity helper class? (@Steps abstraction level above the cucumber stepdefinitions?) Honestly my code is on step definition level is pretty nice, so this could increase the complexity instead... I would like to avoid it and I need only reporting purposes. thanks.